# How to pass file path from action in controller to $.AJAX success function

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

How to pass file path from action in controller to $.AJAX success function.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult OrgLevelReport(string startdate, string enddate)
{
    string file = "D:/Sample.xlsx";
    return Json(file);
}
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("OrgLevelReport", "Reports")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { startdate: startdate, enddate: enddate },
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (bbb) {
        alert(bbb);
        alert("1");
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            try {
                var objExcel;
                objExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
                objExcel.Visible = true;
                objExcel.Workbooks.Open(bbb, false);
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert(e.message);
            }
        } else {
            alert("Your browser does not support this.");
        }
    }
});
```

`alert(bbb)` line displays PK...invalid string and not actual.

Comment: You code seems correct.

Did you put a breakpoint into your action method to ensure that you are actually getting to it ?
Do you have multiple action methods with the same name in your "Reports" controller ?

Comment: @Miiite...Its working now...Below code in actionmethod was causing problem...because response i was getting below was actual excel file in $.ajax success function. //Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=OrgTracker.xlsx"); //Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
                //Response.WriteFile(file);
                //Response.End();